# Pass PHP variables without being seen when working with a database generated list

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

Looking for any help regarding the problem. Here's the deal: I have a database that has a `teams` table and it contains `team_id`. On one of my pages, I generate a list of links that contain the `team_id` of the creator in their get URL. I need the `team_id` on the next page but can't figure out how to pass it through any other way. Using a form and POST isn't an option because this method would only pass through the last links data on the list. Storing in a session isn't an option either because there is no way to discretely pass the the variables I need to a function to set the session variables. I have tried and it can pretty easily be viewed from viewing the source code. So here's some sample code to see exactly what I'm dealing with.

```
<?
if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){ ?>
     <a class="fltrt btn btn-danger btn-small" onclick="test()" href="acceptmatch-exec.php?match_id=<?php echo $match_id; ?>&team_id=<?php echo $team_id;?>&action=cancel">Cancel Match</a>
 <?}else{?>
     <a class="fltrt btn btn-success btn-small" href="acceptmatch-exec.php?match_id=<?php echo $match_id; ?>&team_id=<?php echo $team_id;?>&action=accept">Accept Match</a>
  <?} ?>
```

The code above is generated multiple times on a page via a while loop that was excluded. I want to pass the `match_id` and `team_id` variables without being seen anywhere. If I made this a form, it wouldn't pass the correct variables unless there is only one result at the time (not likely). I'm sure there has to be an easy method that is eluding me, so please share thoughts on how to solve this. I feel as though I am not explaining it well enough, but it's not really easy to explain. I basically want something that works like GET but acts like POST and can be hidden from people viewing source code or link locations.

Thanks

Comment: It's sounds like you do in fact want a session variable. I think you misunderstand how to set SESSION vars. You don't need a function, though I really don't see any reason why that would prevent you from using session.  You can just do $_SESSION['teamId'][] = $team_id; in your loops

Comment: It seems you are confusing which parts of your page run on server and which run on client side. If the project you are working is really serious, my advice is to move away from plain, raw, PHP, and use some framework which allows separtion of code and presentation templates, even if still using PHP.

Comment: I understand that I can use a session variable to pass the variable unseen, I just need a way of setting it depending on which button is clicked in the results. @jsbueno - I know that PHP runs before anything else and is serverside whereas the other stuff is executed afterwards. Just need help with a method to complete the task.

Answer (score 1):

People can't see your source code *from your server*, as long as you don't publish it somewhere else.

If you want to hide IDs, just [hash](hashing method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) them:

```
<a href="someScript.php?id=<?php echo md5($id) ?>">Da Link</a>
```

then in `someScript.php` you'll have to look your db [via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) please!] for:

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE MD5(id) = :id
```

But md5 hashing is very easy to reverse nowadays so you won't be attackers-proof.

Anyway as long as your site is properly built, you can hide resources upon your need without relying on sessions, hashes or whatever: just make good use of [authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

---

I frankly advise you to read some good stuff about how server side development in order to write good code without reinventing the wheel every time - stick with the Symfony guides I linked above, though you won't end using the whole framework [idea I strongly recommend anyway] you will find them very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that source code can't be seen from my server, but it can be viewed from inside a web browser(except php markup). I am actually pretty familiar with web programming in general, but this problem has stumped me so far. Perhaps I didn't elaborate enough in my post. I just need a way to pass variables unseen depending on which row of the database result is selected.

Comment: @Wilcoholic I just can't see why you want to "hide" your variables - is it a security issue? A privacy one? World is full of numeric IDs [see the url up there in your navigation bar!], if you want to keep things hidden mark their paths behind an auth firewall.

Comment: It's not a security issue, it's a cheating issue. My website will be a place where teams can play games competitively and I don't want them to be able to see the team id's associated with the match requests. You can see how they can use that to their advantage.